# My Orchid plant is developing blisters on leaves

Tags: houseplants, indoors, orchids

I have observed that one side of the orchid plant has developed these blisters with faded color leaves.

[image: Orchid leaves with Blister]

While the other side seems to be completely healthy. Can you tell me what could be the reason?
[image: Orchid leaves on the other side healthy]

Answer (score 1):

Are you watering your orchids too much? Or, is your soil or growing medium remains soggy?

From your pictures, it looks like [orchid edema](https://staugorchidsociety.org/PDF/EdemaBlistersonOrchidsbySueBottom.pdf). However, I may also be caused by excess heat or sunburn.

Orchids are relatively delicate and prefers moist environments. However, too much watering would harm them just like any other plant. Adapted to shadowy undergrowth of forests, they cannot tolerate too much sunlight. Blister-like abnormalities form on orchid leaves when the plant is over-watered or the particular leaves are exposed to high heat or sunlight.

However, sometimes it may be pests also. If an insect pest has caused the blisters, there would be noticeable patterns in the damaged leaves. And, although very small, the culprit insects would be visible to the naked eye.

So, check whether you are over-watering or exposing your orchid to an unfavorable degree of sunlight. If none of these are true, then check for signs of insect infestation. If it is caused by over-watering or sunlight exposure, remove the causes of the problem, and over time, the orchid will return to its healthy self. Removing insects are harder, and you might require using pesticides.